# How to make a toast message in Honeycomb?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-3.0-honeycomb, message, toast

I know this might seem quite trivial, however, I've been tackling with it for quite some time.

I'm trying to simply display an error message through a TOAST in honeycomb. However, if I use the traditional Toast method, the app crashes.

From what I found (not very clear) the TOAST method must be in its own thread (?)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and sorry if this is a really noob question...

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.hseactivity);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, an error occurred...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: What does logcat say about the crash? (stacktrace)

Comment: post the error and the code please, otherwise we sill not be able to help you!

Comment: Sorry guys...I sorted it out...Apparently it was because of my emulator. I made a new one and it works. Sorry for taking up your time and posting here before checking more thoroughly...

Comment: Why don't you use this? I think it is a valid context in an Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try cleaning the project and then rebuild it. It happens quite often that android breaks the code and you end up with this kind of odd errors.